# Reversing database changes in Neo4J

Tags: database, neo4j

I'm developing a Wiki application using Neo4J as database. I was wondering about what is/are the correct(s) procedure(s) to track users edits to topics so that mods can reverse them when needed.

I was thinking about saving every modified node before every change and keeping the old versions for a couple of weeks or so, but that doesn't seem like a very fast/efficient procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like an efficient method, but it's really the only method. You can improve upon it a bit, but you have to store the old data somewhere. What I would do is attach a transaction handler to your database. Then whenever a transaction is committed, collect the properties that were changed/removed and store them somewhere. By storing only the modified properties, you'll save yourself a bit of space. I would probably store them in another DB, but that's entirely up to you.

You could also use the incremental backup feature, but that requires the Enterprise Edition of Neo4j. (Which is probably your better option if possible.)

EDIT: The transaction handler can be found [here](http://api.neo4j.org/1.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html). Implement that interface, then register it with the database by using the [registerTransactionEventHandler](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#registerTransactionEventHandler%28org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionEventHandler%29) method in GraphDatabaseService. Your code will be called every time a transaction is committed (and since Neo4j requires all changes to be in transactions, it'll be called any time a change is made).

The TransactionEventHandler interface is a bit difficult to work with. The data they pass you is everything you need, but it's in a very odd format. If you need help with that, feel free to ask here on SO. There's plenty of people (including me) who could help you with that.

Unfortunately, I think this has to be done in Java (or any JVM language, I use Scala). But since Neo4j is already running a JVM, you don't have to start another one to do this. Also, if you're looking for a way to get the data from the TransactionEventHandler to Node.js, I use [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) for that exact purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a question: what do you mean by "attach a transaction handler to your database"? Is this done via [cypher](http://api.neo4j.org/1.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html) or in the server-side code (I'm using node.js)? Also, has this procedure a name (for further research on the subject)? Thanks